# Perform background operation when slider changes in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, slider, backgroundworker

I have a slider and with the valu change of the slider I need to perform some calculation. As the calculation is taking 100-200 ms slider is getting stucked. Is there any way to make those calculation backgroud (In that case, I need to access some values from main thread) and still show the latest output.

Comment: ASP.NET or windows application?

Comment: And if Windows, is it WPF or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

From the BackgroundWorker Thread you can access the Main Thread with

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher
```

In code you could something like
    function X(int newSliderValue)
    {
        UpdateUI(() => { SliderControl.Value = newSliderValue; });
    }

And the call to the dispactcher looks like

```
private void UpdateUI(Action methode)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(methode, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your long calculations are IO bounding operations the best way is to use async/await feature. Mark your handler as async and than use async/await:

```
        var res = await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000); // perform long calculation
                    return e.NewValue*2;
                }
            );
        MessageBox.Show(res.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Pay attention that you don't need some kind of invocation to acces the GUI thread after operations are finished.

If your operations are CPU-bounding you may use tasks like this:

```
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // perform long calculation
            return e.NewValue*2;
        }).ContinueWith(task => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show(task.Result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))));
```

Pay attention that in this case I use dispatcher for WPF (in winform Form class have **Invoke()** method itself).

Also when you start calculations it makes sense to block the slider until calculations are finished because user may change it again and again.